# Offline Time-trial license key that is not prone to users changing system clock

Tags: c#, cryptography, licensing

I have written my own license generator and validation. My application has to be able to work without an internet connection so I am crossing out online activation from my list. License has an expiration date and if it passes the date, the application will not run. But this method is always prone to user changing system clock. What other security measure can I take to strengthen my licensing?

Answer (score 1):

If you really have to create a offline license, I highly suggest a useage count system over a time based system. So you could say, that they can start the application 1000 times and then the license expired. You could also check if another start just happened a few seconds before and then do not count downwards.

And also to mention, what ever system you use, even an extreme system with good encryption that everything is hackable on the client as long as you remove the internet. And to be honest, nowadays there is just 0.1% reason for not having a internet connection.

What u could do, make a server for managing licenses, and when they have to go offline, they can borrow a license for x uses.

Comment: Please write proper english. There is no *u*, but only *you*.

Comment: I can tell you that it's more than 0.1%. The majority of our customers (financial companies, governments etc.) don't accept an internet connection on their servers for security reasons.

Comment: Why not just for the few special cases of customers you have, submit a unlocked version? Just don't tell the customer that it is open, tell it is open to them.